# JDK8 build error langtools

Tags: java-8, java

I'm trying to build JDK8 but I have an error :

```
Building OpenJDK for target 'default' in configuration 'linux-x86_64-normal-server-release'

## Starting langtools
/bin/sh: ligne 0 : cd: /home/damien/jdk8/langtools/make: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
/home/damien/jdk8//make/Main.gmk:83: recipe for target 'langtools-only' failed
make: *** [langtools-only] Error 1
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: I'm translating here: `Ligne 0` is French for `Line 0`; `Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type` is French for `No file or directory of that type`.

Comment: From what I gather from the error message there is no directory or file named `/home/damien/jdk8/langtools/make`. I don't work on unix/linux style OS and I certainly never tried to build JDK's, so that's about all i can say.

Answer (score 5):

1. First, you shoud cd to the jdk source home;
2. And then run  `./get_source.sh`, if this command return WARNING,try it again;
3. Now, you can configure and build again;

   Good luck to you.